# String manipulation in Batch Files

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I have a batch file question

```
Set "filename=C:\Documents\Example.doc"
```

I have a string %FILENAME% and I want to replace the C:\ with C::\, without just redefining it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, and your variant of putting all of the set command in quotes is awkward, albeit valid, but anyway:

```
SET filename=%filename:C:\=C::\%
```

Or you just use the `%filename:C:\=C::\%` expression in places where you want the other value, without actually changing the content of the `Filename` variable.

For more details see (the output of) `SET /?`.